# Как внедрить 3D модель внутри Android-приложения?

Tags: android, 3d

В мое приложение под Android (разрабатываю в Android Studio) необходимо добавить модель помещения. Нарисую это помещение, скажем, в Blender. А как быть дальше? Как добавить его через Android Studio?

Comment: Ах, да. Я слышал за Unity3d-android, но так понял это используется в основном для создания каких-то игр. Более того, мне бы не очень хотелось пытаться переводить весь проект из Android Studio в Unity-3d...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы можете использовать код из данного open-source проекта: https://github.com/andresoviedo/android-3D-model-viewer

Глубоко не вникал, но окно просмотра 3Д модели реализовано в [этом классе](https://github.com/andresoviedo/android-3D-model-viewer/blob/f1bb7ed654ac6dbe68dd37aac4c1ff67adc31912/app/src/main/java/org/andresoviedo/app/model3D/view/ModelSurfaceView.java).

Также нужно будет внедрить библиотеки в проект, их можно найти в grandle.

Comment: Хорошо бы пример использования привести в ответе.